# Angular 2 ViewChild in <router-outlet>

Tags: angular

I'm developing an angular 2 application.
In the `MainComponent` I have references to the child components with `@ViewChild`. 
In this `MainComponent` I have a `<router-outlet>` where I'm loading different components.
My question is, How can I have references to those components loaded in `<router-outlet>`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The `<router-outlet>` provides an event that emits the component instance when one is added:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="routedComponent = $event"></router-outlet>
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/42cf06fa12924882d18d1167432214fdc66b1158/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L113